# delphi form creation

Tags: delphi

I have created an application in delphi 7. My Main form calls the execute procedure of subform.  Execute procedure creates the object of subform and displays the subform to user. I have removed the subform from auto creation. Now i have added one edit box on subform and tried to set the text after the subform created in execute procedure. But in this case i am getting access violation error. If i use subform.editbox to set text then it will not give any error. Is it always mandotary to use components with form referance when form is not auto created? thanks for help.

```
function TSubForm.execute(temp:String);
begin
  frmSubForm:= TSubForm.create(self);
  edit1.text:= temp;
  frmSubForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

Comment: If form is not autcreated then its mandotory to use form referance? like frmSubForm.edit1.text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is dangerous. A method can implicitly access all fields of the object even though it might not have been created yet. Try to make it a class method instead:

```
class function TSubForm.execute(temp:String);
begin
  frmSubForm:= TSubForm.create(self);
  edit1.text:= temp;
  frmSubForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

(also adapt it in the class declaration)
After that change, the compiler will no longer let you access edit1 because it is not a variable of the class but rather of an instance of that class. So the correct code would be:

```
class function TSubForm.execute(temp:String);
begin
  frmSubForm:= TSubForm.create(self);
  frmSubForm.edit1.text:= temp;
  frmSubForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

But beware: Your frmSubForm variable is not declared inside the method, so it probably is global. Where do you free the form? This would be cleaner:

```
class function TSubForm.execute(temp:String);
begin
  frm:= TSubForm.create(self);
  try
    frm.edit1.text:= temp;
    frm.ShowModal;
  finally
    frm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

(btw: Your function does not have a return type.)

Answer (score 3):

Form is not much different to other Objects. You need to create it (either with `Application.CreateForm(..)` or manually with `Form2 := TForm2.Create(..)`). Unless it's created, of course you will get an AccessViolation as the Form2 = nil.

**EDIT**

A. You did not specified where and how `frmSubForm` is declared. Is it meant to be a separate instance of `TSubForm` form?

B. It looks like you run `function TSubForm.execute(temp:String);` from yet not created form. Maybe this should be a class function.

C. You effectively access `Self.edit1` where's in your question you sound like you wanted to access `frmSubForm.edit1`

Comment: I have created the form in the start of execute procedure using Tform2.create(..). After that i have used editbox to set text.

Comment: Did you assigned it `Form2 := TForm2.Create(..)` ?

Comment: 1.frmSubForm is instance of TSubForm declared in same unit. 2. I just called execute function by adding subform in uses of Mainform.  3. I wanted to know why there is difference between auto creation and manual creation.

Comment: 2 is your mistake. You are accessing yet uncreated forms Execute function ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical code for using non-autocreated form (TForm2):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm2;

begin
  Form:= TForm2.Create(Application);
  try
    Form.Edit1.Text:= 'Hello';
    Form.ShowModal;
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you want to show Form2 as non-modal (`Show` instead of `ShowModal`) you should set its close action to `caFree` in `OnClose` handler:

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action:= caFree;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm2;

begin
  Form:= TForm2.Create(Application);
  Form.Edit1.Text:= 'Hello';
  Form.Show;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should acces your textbox text like this:

```
function TSubForm.execute(temp:String);
begin
  frmSubForm:= TSubForm.create(self);
  frmSubForm.edit1.text:= temp;
  frmSubForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

Also, call Free on your subform, after you have done with it.

Comment: If i added that form in auto creation then there is no need to use like frmSubForm.edit1. We can assign it directly by edit1.text. But why we have to give referenace in manual creation?

Comment: If this form is auto-created, you need to call frmSubForm.edit1 too. There's no difference in that.

Comment: I have tested. If i added subform in auto create and do not use TSubForm.create(self); then there will not be any error while using only edt1.text.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think I would do it this way, but this works:

```
unit UfrmSubForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TfrmSubForm = class(TForm)
    edit1: TEdit;
  private
    procedure Set_EditText(const Value: String);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    class function Execute(Temp: String): TModalResult;
    property EditText: String write Set_EditText;
  end;


function SubFormExecute(Temp: String): TModalResult;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TfrmSubForm }

class function TfrmSubForm.Execute(Temp: String): TModalResult;
var
  frmSubForm: TfrmSubForm;
begin
  frmSubForm := TfrmSubForm.Create(Application);
  try
   frmSubForm.EditText := Temp;
   Result := frmSubForm.ShowModal;
  finally
   frmSubForm.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmSubForm.Set_EditText(const Value: String);
begin
  edit1.Text := Value;
end;

end.
```

Then use it from the first form like so:

```
procedure TForm1.btnExecuteClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TfrmSubForm.Execute('Some Text');
end;
```

Returning the status of a `ShowModal` does not hurt, you never know when you may need it.

You probably should not access properties of other objects (form or otherwise) children directly; use a propery of the parent object in case the TEdit becomes a TLabel in the future you only have to change the frmSubForm once, not very place that accesses frmSubForm.Edit.Text.

Comment: I liked @dummzeuch idea, so I modified my answer to use a class function and a local variable for the form.